# How to change address of Master Boot Record

Tags: boot, mbr

Can we change the location ( Starting and Ending address ) of Master Boot Record of a bootable device ? Doing so is  operating system dependent or not ? If we can change the location of Master Boot Record then how we do it for Linux OS and for Windows Os ?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. The MBR is *always* at the beginning of sector 0 of the disk (440 bytes of boot code, the rest for partition table). This is not OS-dependent, as the firmware itself (the BIOS) must also know where the boot record is.

However, the MBR can load a bootloader from elsewhere on the disk; many existing bootloaders work that way because they cannot fit in the MBR (e.g. the syslinux MBR just looks for a file `ldlinux.sys` and loads it).